# I am running into this error "TypeError: argument callback must be a function when provided"

Tags: mysql, node.js

I get the error mentioned in the title when I try to query MySQL database to insert data. This is my first time working with Express Js so I am new to this.

Can someone look at my code and point out what I am doing wrong here?

```
if (result && result.length)
    res.json('User already exists');
else {
    connection.query('INSERT INTO `users`(`name`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `salt`, `unique_id`)',
                     'VALUES (?,?,?,NOW(),NOW(),?,?)', [name, email, password, salt, uid], function (err, results, fields) {
    connection.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('[MySQL ERROR]', err);
        res.json('Register error:', err);
    });
    res.json('Registered successfully');
}
```

Comment: what is the `orm` library that you are using? I guess the first and seecond argument for `connection.query` should be a single string.

Comment: If I make the first and second argument a single string I get "TypeError: val.slice is not a function" error.  I am using Express js

Comment: It looks like your first 2 parameters ('INSERT INTO...' and 'VALUES...') should all be one string (using WHERE probably) so that you're only sending 3 parameters to the `query` function

Comment: After debugging the error seems to be coming from [name, email, password, salt, uid], any bette way to do this?